# Removing elements from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array that looks like this

```
 $hours_worked = array('23',0,'24',0)
```

What want to do is to loop through the array and remove the element that contains 0

What I have so far is:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($hours_worked); $i++) 
{
   if($hours_worked[$i] === 0 )
   {
       unset($hours_worked[$i]);
   }    
}
```

However the result I get is `$hours_worked = array(23,24,0)`. I.e. it does not remove the final element from the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Use [foreach](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZFkQi7) — P.S. Your problem is looping over the array by index, while not taking into account the fact that you're reducing the size of the array when unsetting.

Comment: Yep this was the exact code I was using. When I change it to double zero, it produces the same outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code is that you are calculating `count($hours_worked)` on each iteration; once you remove an item the count will decrease, which means that for each item removed the loop will terminate before seeing one item at the end of the array. So an immediate way to fix it would be to pull the count out of the loop:

```
$count = count($hours_worked);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   // ...
}
```

That said, the code can be further improved. For one you should always use `foreach` instead of `for` -- this makes the code work on all arrays instead of just numerically indexed ones, and is also immune to counting problems:

```
foreach ($hours_worked as $key => $value) {
    if ($value === 0) unset($hours_worked[$key]);
}
```

You might also want to use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) for this kind of work because it's an easy one-liner:

```
$hours_worked = array('23',0,'24',0);
$hours_worked = array_diff($hours_worked, array(0)); // removes the zeroes
```

If you choose to do this, be aware of how `array_diff` compares items:

> Two elements are considered equal if and only if `(string) $elem1 ===
>   (string) $elem2`. In words: when the string representation is the
>   same.

Answer (score -1):

Try foreach loops instead

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($hours_worked as $hour) {
   if($hour != '0') {
      $new_array[] = $hour;
   }
}
// $new_array should contain array(23, 24)
```

Comment: Whats the reason for downvote :(